# Why tf.placeholder of string type doesn't work for tf.string_input_producer()

Tags: python, tensorflow

In a scenario that I want to dynamically change the input file names to the file names queue utilizing placeholder, so I can loop through files. However I find the following code doesn't work, anyone has an idea?

```
import tensorflow as tf

def test(s):
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([s])

    reader = tf.TextLineReader()
    key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)

    record_defaults = [[1.0], [1]]
    col1, col2 = tf.decode_csv(value, record_defaults = record_defaults)

    return col1, col2

s = tf.placeholder(tf.string, None, name = 's')
# s = tf.constant('file0.csv', tf.string)
ss = ["file0.csv", "file1.csv"]
inputs, labels = test(s)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

    for e in ss:
        inputs_val, labels_val = sess.run([inputs, labels], feed_dict = {s: e})
        print("input {} - label {}".format(inputs_val, labels_val))

    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

Thanks for the help of looking into it.

(tensorflow)[yuming@atlas1 working-files]$ python 36.py

```
2017-10-11 11:28:40.825044: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:965] Found device 0 with properties:
name: Quadro M4000 major: 5 minor: 2 memoryClockRate(GHz): 0.7725
pciBusID: 0000:83:00.0
totalMemory: 7.93GiB freeMemory: 7.87GiB
2017-10-11 11:28:40.931938: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:965] Found device 1 with properties:
name: Quadro K2200 major: 5 minor: 0 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.124
pciBusID: 0000:03:00.0
totalMemory: 3.95GiB freeMemory: 3.47GiB
2017-10-11 11:28:40.931990: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:980] Device peer to peer matrix
2017-10-11 11:28:40.931998: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:986] DMA: 0 1
2017-10-11 11:28:40.932002: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:996] 0:   Y N
2017-10-11 11:28:40.932005: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:996] 1:   N Y
2017-10-11 11:28:40.932013: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1055] Creating TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0) -> (device: 0, name: Quadro M4000, pci bus id: 0000:83:00.0, compute capability: 5.2)
2017-10-11 11:28:40.932018: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1042] Ignoring gpu device (device: 1, name: Quadro K2200, pci bus id: 0000:03:00.0, compute capability: 5.0) with Cuda multiprocessor count: 5. The minimum required count is 8. You can adjust this requirement with the env var TF_MIN_GPU_MULTIPROCESSOR_COUNT.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "36.py", line 26, in <module>
    inputs_val, labels_val = sess.run([inputs, labels], feed_dict = {s: 'file0.csv'})
  File "/home/yuming/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 889, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/yuming/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1118, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/yuming/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1315, in _do_run
    options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/yuming/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1334, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OutOfRangeError: FIFOQueue '_0_input_producer' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 1, current size 0)
         [[Node: ReaderReadV2 = ReaderReadV2[_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](TextLineReaderV2, input_producer)]]

Caused by op u'ReaderReadV2', defined at:
  File "36.py", line 17, in <module>
    inputs, labels = test(s)
  File "36.py", line 7, in test
    key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)
  File "/home/yuming/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/io_ops.py", line 194, in read
    return gen_io_ops._reader_read_v2(self._reader_ref, queue_ref, name=name)
  File "/home/yuming/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_io_ops.py", line 654, in _reader_read_v2
    queue_handle=queue_handle, name=name)
  File "/home/yuming/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 789, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/yuming/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3052, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/yuming/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1610, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): FIFOQueue '_0_input_producer' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 1, current size 0)
         [[Node: ReaderReadV2 = ReaderReadV2[_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](TextLineReaderV2, input_producer)]]
```

Comment: Please post the error you are getting.

Comment: @TheMyth: sorry for incomplete information. The output is added as above, seems no direct error related to the intended approach.

However, when using tf.constant instead of tf.placeholder, it can work.

file0.csv and file1.csv are quite simple csv files just with two lines:

0.1,0
0.9,1

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this with `tf.train.string_input_producer`. One possible option is to use `tf.FIFOQueue` directly (also used by `string_input_producer` under the hood) and fill it with file names manually instead.

```
filename_queue = tf.FIFOQueue(capacity=100, dtypes=[tf.string])
with tf.Session() as session:
  reader = tf.TextLineReader()
  key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)
  col1, col2, col3, col4, target = tf.decode_csv(value, record_defaults=[[1.], [1.], [1.], [1.], [1.]])
  coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
  threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

  session.run(filename_queue.enqueue("file0.csv"))
  for i in range(10):
    print session.run(target)

  session.run(filename_queue.enqueue("file1.csv"))
  for i in range(10):
    print session.run(target)

  # NOTE: if I call this one more time, it'll hang, because
  # the queue is empty and the last CSV is fully read
  #
  # print session.run(target)

  coord.request_stop()
  coord.join(threads)
```

Both of my CSV files have 10 rows and 5 columns, so I use `range(10)` and it works as I expect: first `file0.csv`, then `file1.csv`.

**Be careful: if you are not feeding enough examples, the main thread will hang**.

I suggest you always keep the queue not empty and keep adding files to it. This way you can feed the queue dynamically and in any order.